# How to verify 7zip'd files integrity

Tags: compression, hashing

For some files I have compressed, I have been looking for a `MD5` add-on to `7zip` (As I have the MD5's by way of an Explorer Column Handler, in `xplorer2`); or a `CRC` Explorer Column Handler (Because 7Zip provides the `CRC` of a file in an archive, but `xplorer2` only calculates `Checksums` natively, as a way of doing basic / virtually categorical checking, that the contents of the 7z compressed file are currently going to extract to be the same as the files they came from, before deleting the originals.

However, I believe there is a flaw in my thinking here...

Am I correct in assuming that none of the `Checksum/CRC/MD5` etc calculations will be the same as the uncompressed versions?

If not, any suggestions on how to provide some peace of mind?